# interesting relationship involving the growth of differences between log integral and prime counting function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Wondering about the following where my $f(x)$ is defined further down:

$$|f(x)-\pi(x)|-|f(x)-\text{Li}(x)|\approx |\text{Li(x)}-\pi(x)|~~~(*)$$

In the sense that the difference between the LHS and RHS is bounded by some constant $c<N.$

I guess my main questions are:

> Can $(*)$ be proven?

> Why does $(*)$ seem to hold? Is there some hidden relation going on between $h,g,f$ and $\text{Li}(x)$ and $\pi(x)?$

$$f(x)=\frac{h(x)+g(x)}{2}$$

where we introduce two functions that gauge the distribution of primes: $$h(x)= \sum_{p \le x} \exp\bigg(\frac{1}{\log p}\bigg) $$

and $$g(x)= \sum_{p \le x} \exp\bigg(\frac{-1}{\log p}\bigg). $$

Here you can see $g(x)$ in blue, $h(x)$ in red and $f(x)$ in green:

[image]

Below you can see that tau:=$ |\text{Li(x)}-\pi(x)|$ and phi:=$|f(x)-\pi(x)|-|f(x)-\text{Li}(x)|$ are nearly identical up to at least $x=4,000,000.$ This is quite amazing in my opinion and I'm not sure of the reason behind it...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's less here than meets the eye, I think. Since $f(x)>\pi(x)$ always (by the AM/GM inequality), the right-hand side of (*) exceeds the left-hand side by *exactly*
$$
\begin{cases}
2\bigl( \mathop{\rm Li}(x) - f(x) \bigr), & \text{if } \mathop{\rm Li}(x)\ge f(x), \\
0, & \text{if } f(x) \ge \mathop{\rm Li}(x)\ge \pi(x), \\
2\bigl( \pi(x) - \mathop{\rm Li}(x) \bigr), & \text{if } \pi(x) \ge \mathop{\rm Li}(x).
\end{cases}
$$
(And this is true for any function $f(x)$ that exceeds $\pi(x)$, not just this particular one.) On average $\mathop{\rm Li}(x)$ is about $\sqrt x/\log x$ larger than $\pi(x)$, but $f(x)$ is asmptotically $\frac12 \frac x{(\log x)^3}$ larger than $\mathop{\rm Li}(x)$; so the second case is the most common one. But the difference between the two sides will infinitely often be as large as a constant times $\sqrt x(\log\log\log x)/\log x$ by Littlewood's theorem, hence definitely not bounded by a constant.